# Episerver multi-site best practices/approaches?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, episerver

Currently, our single-project Episerver solution serves up a single website and has been working great. Soon we'll be developing an additional, separate Episerver site that will need to live within the same solution but I would love for the two codebases to remain separate while still sharing the same Episerver DB. For the site that currently exists, we have a lot of page/block models, so I expect any refactoring will be no light lift.

Is there any documentation/guidance, [aside from this](https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/Deployment/Setting-up-multiple-sites/), that details out best practices on how to separate out the models, controllers, views, etc for each site into their own project?

Is this better achieved through the use of Areas instead of separate projects? Some other approach I'm not considering?

Any help and/or discussion around this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I ask why you would combine the codebases? That is sort of the last resort, something we are forced to do when hosting in DXC and the client is to cheap to actually pay for an additional web app (which will cost you about 40-50% of the first DXC app).

Comment: with multisite approach, you'll have the same web application and the same database for all the sites. nothing prevents editors from using any page and any block on any site. you can try to work around that with setting content (type and instance) permissions, or custom dynamic logic in metadata extenders, or restricting types through available types attributes, but I see that as a lot of custom logic which just won't work as a whole. having these - do you really want to try to separate everything? if yes - first step would be putting all the controllers into separate projects ==>>

Comment: ==>> to do that, you'll need to put all the models (pages / blocks) into separate project, and abstract some logic (generating menus, finding page lists, whatever) into yet another separate project
if you manage to make that work - you'll have separate projects for (at least) views/site, controllers, models and logic. having this - nothing stops you from splitting it further based on site or whatever semantic you'll choose

Comment: @EricHerlitz - The core reason to combine both sites is because we want to share a handful of global settings that both sites will need to share, such as a general navigation structure, product settings, etc.

Comment: @ianpoley Alright, go check Valdis post on Areas, there are some blog posts linked in the bottom of the description as well. https://github.com/valdisiljuconoks/MvcAreasForEPiServer

Comment: @EricHerlitz - This is exactly the approach I ended up going with. Fairly straight forward to implement and will undoubtedly be easier to manage in future Epi upgrades when comparing to the multi-project approach. Thanks Eric!